# how can i build algorithm in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a problem to build an algorithm in Matlab.

Given: `x(1)` and `x(2)`

Then:

```
x(3)=(x(1) + x(2))/2

x(4)=(x(1) + x(3))/2

x(5)=(x(3) + x(2))/2

x(6)=(x(1) + x(4))/2

x(7)=(x(3) + x(2))/2

...
```

i.e.

let `x(1)=0`, and `x(2)=1`, then `x(3)=0.5` (midpoint), `x(4)=0.25` (midpoint between `x(1)` and `x(3)`), `x(5)=0.75` (midpoint between `x(3)` and `x(2)`), `x(6)` is the midpoint between `x(1)` and `x(4)`, `x(7)` is the midpoint between `x(3)` and `x(5)` ...

That means the first iteration results in 3 points (`x(1)`,`x(3)` and `x(2)`), the second iteration results in 5 points (`x(1)`, `x(4)`, `x(3)`, `x(5)` and `x(2)`), third iteration results in 9 points (`x(1)`, `x(6)`, `x(4)`, `x(7)`, `x(3)`, `x(8)`, `x(5)`, `x(9)`  and  `x(2)`). Finally, the `n`th iteration would result in `(2^n+1)` points.

How can I implement this logic using Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you made yourself clear. :)

What you want is this:

```
clear x;
x(1) = 7; % For example
x(2) = 11; % For example

nIter = 3;

for i = 1:nIter
    newX = zeros(1, 2 * numel(x) - 1);
    newX(1:2:end) = x;
    newX(2:2:end) = (x(1:end-1) + x(2:end)) / 2;
    x = newX;
end

disp(x)
```

However, if you look at the result, you'll see that what you're doing is the same as this:

```
clear x;
x(1) = 7;
x(2) = 11;

nIter = 3;

x2 = linspace(x(1), x(2), 2 ^ nIter + 1);

disp(x)
```

Comment: @user3527075, if this answered your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the tick mark on the left side of the answer. Thanks!